# Composer library dependencies not included on web host

Tags: composer-php

I'm using a library management program called Composer on my device. I used it to install a library which it placed in a folder called vendor. My web application works fine locally. However, it gives me a bunch of php include errors even though I uploaded in the same folder hierarchy. I suspect this is because of the composer.json file which signals the required libraries, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you upload the vendor folder too?

Comment: Can you give the EXACT error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me awhile ago, to fix this. Here is what i've done:

1. I removed my vendor folder on my working directory on the web host
2. thru ssh, i've installed composer, and then re-run composer install on my working directory.
3. after that everything worked